# sudo systemctl start nginx error. Server wont start

Tags: nginx

I am having trouble with my nginx server not wanting to start. could someone with the appropriate knowledge try to diagnose my error code and give me some kind of guidance as to how I can fix my issue? This is my first time posting so if you need anymore information please let me know. Thanks (:

```
michael@productionserver1:~$ sudo systemctl start nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
michael@productionserver1:~$ systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-07-14 05:50:29 EDT; 16s ago
  Process: 3754 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/
  Process: 2269 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=ex
  Process: 3598 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, statu
  Process: 5641 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exit
 Main PID: 3600 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
lines 1-8/8 (END)
```

I got this when running " nginx -t " `nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log"                                                                  failed: (13 Permission denied)                                                                      2016/07/14 07:32:23 [warn] 6060#6060: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-suer privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1                                                                                     2016/07/14 07:32:23 [emerg] 6060#6060: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:44                                                                                                       3 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:34                                                   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf text failed`

Comment: Check nginx error log file and run `nginx -t` to check its configuration file for any syntax errors.

Comment: You'll need to run `sudo nginx -t` to check syntax and config. (Without `sudo` you get the permission denied error). On a different note, you've defined 2 default servers listening on the same port. Search your config files in `sites-enabled` and check your `listen` directives.